# How to display data that I get from Database.SqlQuery in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is the code snippet.

```
string query = "SELECT EnrollmentDate, COUNT(*) AS StudentCount "
            + "FROM Person "
            + "WHERE Discriminator = 'Student' "
            + "GROUP BY EnrollmentDate";

IEnumerable<EnrollmentDateGroup> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<EnrollmentDateGroup>(query);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\log.txt", data.ToString()); // or ToList()?
```

Now from my last line of code, I am getting a file with basically the same text that's there in the query. What I want to be displayed in my text file is the actual data from the database? How do I get that?

Answer (score 2):

`data.ToString()` returns the information about the class, not the data. You need to do like this

```
StringBuildet text = new StringBuilder();

data.ToList().ForEach(d => text.Append(/* Here what you want to do with each item of the EnrollmentDataGroup /*));

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\log.txt", text);
```

First you need to cast to List for using the **ForEach**.
Or you can write your own `ForEach` method for the type of **IEnumerable**

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the love of anything that's holy to you (the FSM for me) use a `StringBuilder` instead of repeated string concatenation !

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx